# issue with resize() function, when growing widths

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a fixed div on the right of window, what i want to do is when the user resize the window, i want this fixed div not to overlap with the other div by changing it's positioning, i managed to do that when resizing to smaller, but what i want, is when the user also resize the window for higher widths, i want that div to go back to the initial "fixed" state.

Here is the code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var pos = $("#div").offset();
        var fix = $("#fix").offset();
        if(fix.left<950){
            $('#fix').css('position','relative');
            $('#fix').css('left',fix.left);
            $('#fix').css('top',-fix.top);
            var available = true;
        }
        var pos = $("div").offset();
        var fix = $("fix").offset();
        if(fix.left>950){
            $('#fix').css('position','fixed');
            $('#fix').css('right','100px');
            $('#fix').css('top',fix.top);
        }
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body style="margin:0;">
<div id="div" style="width:600px; height:200px; background-color:red; margin-left:300px;"></div>
<div id="fix" style="position:fixed; right:100px; height:100px; width:100px; background-color:yellow; top:100px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks every one in advance !

Answer (score 0):

As I can see that the action takes place when your window is resized to less that a fixed value or resized to greater than the same value hence
I would **Suggest you to use CSS3 Media** Queries rather than Script for the **Responsive/ Adaptive Web page design.**

Please have a look at [this](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries)

These **do not process a lot**, hence **Light weight and most modern browsers and Devices support CSS3** hence a **convenient and reliable Option.**

Besides if you target old browsers and need to show rounded corners or other css3 properties not supported by old browsers you may have a look at the CSS3 PIE on the link: css3pie.com

Comment: i'm sorry but i didn't even mention that my goal was borders or something .. i want the fixed DIV to become relative at specific "left" value, and the same DIV to become fixed on specific "left" values

Comment: Borders ans shoadows have nothing to do with answer. Just some additional info. But Css3 Responsive Design is something I wanted you to see.